# VBA - Excel Showing form after double click on a Cell

Tags: vba, excel

I've encountered a strange Problem. I have an Input Form for the User in Excel.
This Form provides basic CRUD functions to edit a List in a Table. Now this Userform also has a ListBox which shows all the entrys with Id and some basic infos (so you know which entry is which ). Now what I want is, that if you select a row in the normal excel table, and then open the InputForm, the selected row in the table should also be selected in the listBox of the InputForm.

I do this like this:

```
  If Selection.Row >= StartRow() Then
      ListBoxAll.listIndex = Selection.Row - StartRow()      
  Else
      ListBoxAll.listIndex = 0
  End If
```

This works great if I open the Ui per Button click. But if I try to open the form with the Before Double Click Event. I got an Offset.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    UserFormInput.Show
End Sub
```

Now for the strange part. If I check what value the Selection.Row has, by showing it with a MessageBox, it all works fine! But as soon as I remove the MessageBox its broken all over again.

```
    If Selection.Row >= StartRow() Then
        ListBoxAll.listIndex = Selection.Row - StartRow()
        MsgBox Selection.Row
    Else
        ListBoxAll.listIndex = 0
    End If
```

It does not matter where in the if I put the Messagebox.

So the **Question** has anybody ever got the same Problem ? And does anybody know a solution or a workaround to it ? (I don't want to show a Messagebox!)

So I added some screenshots to make it easier to understand.

[image: Table with example data]

[image: Ui with example data]

**Update** I think it has something to do with the Focus after a double click, which is (maybe) on the doubleclicked Cell. And gets changed if I put out a MsgBox

Comment: wait a second, you have two listboxes (with the same entries or just some same entries?) where when you selected one line you want to select the same line (or entry?) in the second listbox? what are you accomplishing with the line "If Selection.row >= StartRow()"?

Comment: No sorry, I have a table, which contains the data, and I have a userform for (CRUD) with a listBox, which shows enough to know which entry you are editing, there you can select a entry. So you don't have to close and open it all the time

Comment: I Changed the Text above, to make it understandable, I try to post some screenshoots after my break =) 

StartRow() gives back the first row of actual data in the table (I have some titles and buttons freezed before the actual data)

Comment: so each time the form is displayed the selected item in the listbox needs to be updated according to the selection of the excel table. what is your worksheet called? what is your form called?

Comment: my Form is called UserFormInput and my Worksheet is called Tabelle1. (Is quite a prototype yet)

Answer (score 1):

(I'll write this as an answer but this is only a part of the code... :)

Oh, german ^.^

I believe each time you call your userform you'll have to compare the selected data to the listbox data. As you have a multicolumn listbox you could do this by the following (I believe, but untested):

```
Dim ThisRow As Integer
ThisRow = ActiveCell.Row
Dim ThisValue As String
ThisValue = ActiveWorkbook.Sheet("Tabelle1").Cells(ThisRow, 1).Value
```

This "1" should be the column which contains the same kind of information as is displayed in the first column of your listbox.

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 to UserFormInput.Listbox1.Listcount
    If UserFormInput.Listbox1.List(i, 0).Value = ThisValue Then
        UserFormInput.Listbox1.List(i).Select
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: First of all thank you for an answer. I understand what you want to do here, but that's not my problem. It could be a workaround, but I am more interested in the difference between Selection.Row and ActiveCell.Row ?
And could it help me to get rid of the strange behaviour ? (as I noted, my method works fine, if it's not triggered by a doubleclick)

Comment: It's just that I learned to evade .selection as much as possible. where is that code actually located?

Comment: in the UserFormInput_Activate()

Comment: Just fyi: I tried it by replacing .selection with activecell.row same strange behaviour, works if I give out the value with a msgbox, but not if I don't do it. going to try your way

Comment: Hm.. this is really strange... can you once try to put debug.print Selection.row after the if-statement?

Comment: Debug.Print yeah something learned ;) (I normaly write in other programming languages)
did that for activecell.row selection.row and for StartRow(). All numbers are correct. So I did it for ListBox.listIndex - also correct. Whats extremely strange. Checked for side-effects could not find anything. That's what happens if you want to write a quick ui for a trivial task ^^

Comment: hmm... does it work if you leave the debug.print in?

Comment: no, it doesn't. My idea was that is some sort of focus problem, because I use the activate_routine, and the focus is still on the double clicked form. I tried to move it to the initialize, but same result

Comment: Can you once try to write this code into another sub and then just call it from the userform_activate()-sub?

Comment: I just realized that my code wouldn't work because in the listbox the values of the first column are the values of two columns from the worksheet...

Comment: yeah but that's not a problem,  I can get your code to work. These values are also not unique ;). But I want to understand this ^^
writing it to a sub doesn't work either

Comment: ok, I'm a newby myself so I probably won't be able to give an explanation to this... :( If my code should work without bugs I believe it has to do something with the .selection. If you get an answer, I will be happy to learn this as well :)